# Run node.js & WebAPI on same server for same site with IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I'm looking to slowly convert a `Node.js` application over to `ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0`. I'm currently using `IIS` and will stick with `IIS`. So, I would like to host them on the same server but direct some URIs over to the new platform.

How would I do this in the `web.config`? The current `web.config` for `node.js` looks like so:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application
           to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="beta/app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^beta/app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="beta/public{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="beta/app.js" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The file structure is:

```
- web.config (the one shown above)
  -> node
      - app.js
      - ...
  -> webapi
      - web.config
      - global.asax
      - ...
```

I was thinking that I should be writing a new rule which lists the URIs to go to the `WebAPI`. But, I'm not quite sure how to do that. My guess is that I would add a condition for each `URI` with the `input` attribute. I was also thinking I should point to the `ASP.NET WebAPI` project but I am even more clueless how I should go about doing that since `Node.js` I'm just pointing at the `app.js` file.

Comment: I think there should be `match` tag in your 2nd and 3rd rule tag. and action should be something like  `<action type="Rewrite" url="beta/app.js?action={R:1}"/>`. {R:1} is matched part in url. Since I don't know what rule you want to apply, you can provide some example.

Comment: thanks for the pointer @kiro. I'm not sure if it applies to what I'm doing since the original node.js `web.config` works fine. You can see what I needed to do in the solution below. I was doing a few things wrong when trying to create the separate projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what I ended up doing. It was actually pretty straight forward. But when you are not familiar with IIS it can be daunting.

I put the original `web.config` in with the `node` directory. I think the `iisnode` handler interferes with `WebAPI` config if you don't. So, the new `node.js` `web.config` in the `node` directory would look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application
           to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For root `web.config` I made it point to static files directly, bypassing `node.js`. Which means I'm going to have to write some custom code to handle rewrites for `gzipped` files - I'll figure that out later. I also added the attribute `stopProcessing` to each `rewrite` `rule`. This was also messing up the code, as it wouldn't actually rewrite where I wanted it too, since the rewrite would be overwritten. Note that the `accept` versioning header hasn't actually been tested yet - I don't have any reason to believe it wouldn't work though. The last `rewrite` points all `uri`s to the `webapi` app by default.

In the `WebAPI` project I had to route all my routes to `webapi/api` since it isn't in the root folder. After I migrate everything from `node.js` I will probably make the `webapi` directory the root folder for the project so it won't need the `webapi` in my routing anymore. But this is all hidden from the client.

So here's the actual code:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <!-- test item for webapi folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent2" stopProcessing="true" >
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/def" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="webapi{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>

        <!-- rewrite static items which exist on node -->
        <rule name="Node Static" stopProcessing="true" >
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*\.[A-Za-z2]{2,5}$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="node/public{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="WebAPI Version 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <conditions>
                <add
                    input="{HEADER_ACCEPT}"
                    pattern="vnd.fieldops.v2"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="webapi{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>

        <!-- rewrite to node for dynamic items -->
        <rule name="Node Dynamic" stopProcessing="true" >
            <conditions>
                <add
                    input="{REQUEST_URI}"
                    pattern="^/api/(dealerservicereports|chat|dealers|dealerequipment|dealercloseout|publications|tokens|users|\?)"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="node/app.js" />
        </rule>

        <!-- rewrite everything else to webapi -->
        <rule name="WebAPI Dynamic" stopProcessing="true" >
            <action type="Rewrite" url="webapi{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```